# Using ajax to pass post data to python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, post

HTML

```
{%  if todo_array %}
<ul>
{% for TodoList in todo_array  %}
   <li class="listItems" name="listItem" id="item{{ forloop.counter }}" onClick = "myFunction({{ forloop.counter }})" >
            {{ TodoList.todo_text }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% else %}
  <p> Add some Todo's !! </p>
{% endif %}
```

Javascript

```
 var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function myFunction(value){
    console.log("clicked")
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
        type:"POST",
        {% load static %}
        url:"{%url 'home'%}",
        data: {
            id : value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success',data);
        },
    });
}
```

Python

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        todelete = request.POST.get('id')
        print(todelete)
    return render(request, 'home/mainList.html', context)
```

I'm trying to send the ID from html using javascript into python by making an ajax call. However the post data isn't working. How can I fix my code?

Edit. 
Getting a server internal error 500 now.

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('logout', views.logout_attempt, name='logout')
]
```

Comment: `isn't working` - explain that a bit more. Error in the browser console? Can you see what the request post data is? What is the response? Have you done anything to debug?

Comment: There's no error in the browser console and I can't see what the request and the post data is. Can you recommend me what I can to do debug?

Comment: is the request even being made? view the source of the page in the browser ... does it look "correct"?

Comment: Nothing shows up on the terminal when I click the list items. So I don't think its being made. Are there any other ways to check this?

Comment: oh ... just realised ... `$.ajaxSetup` that doesn't make a request - surely you want `$.ajax`

Comment: ah thx! The request is being made now but now I'm getting **error code 500 -  internal server error**

Comment: That means it's an error in your python code. Try posting more of your python code, including the routing

Comment: I wasn't sure how to format propely in the comments so I made an edit above.

Comment: `print(todelete)` is likely the cause of the 500 server error.  The first thing that your program outputs has to be an HTTP response header such as `Content-Type: text/html`, or you will get a 500 error.  Normally the web framework handles all that for you, but if your program has any `print` calls, those happen first, and the web server can't decipher it.